# Vend Pagination Returns AttributeError 'Response' object has no attribute 'get' on Second Loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to paginate through sales orders with Vend API search endpoint. The query that I have below has 4315 total records. Since Vend limits each page to 1000 records, then this is a 5 page response. The first iteration of the loop works as expected (offset=0), but the second loop breaks with the error "AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'".

The extremely puzzling thing is when I run the query (https://hooked.vendhq.com/api/2.0/search?date_from=2021-04-01T00:00:00Z&date_to=2021-04-22T23:59:59Z&type=sales&page_size=1000&offset=1000) outside of the loop for the second page it returns data as expected.

No matter what I do within the loop, even if I change the initial offset value to 2000 or 3000, the first loop will work while the second will fail with the same error. Can someone explain why this is happening please? Thanks.

```
import requests

header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'XXXXXXXXX'
}

offset = 0

for i in range(5):
    url_sales_count = 'https://{{domain}}.vendhq.com/api/2.0/search?date_from=2021-04-01T00:00:00Z&date_to=2021-04-22T23:59:59Z&type=sales&page_size=1000&offset=' + str(offset)
    requests = requests.get(url=url_sales_count,headers=header)
    print(requests.status_code)
    offset = offset + 1000
```

Comment: you have overwritten requests import. pls change the variable name inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to be careful that we don't overwrite the existing library import. when you have put `requests = requests.get(url=url_sales_count,headers=header)` you have overwritten **requests** which you have imported. `import requests`. so following will be the way!, i am sure its typo but can be helpful for future readers.

```
import requests

header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'XXXXXXXXX'
}

offset = 0

for i in range(5):
    url_sales_count = 'https://{{domain}}.vendhq.com/api/2.0/search?date_from=2021-04-01T00:00:00Z&date_to=2021-04-22T23:59:59Z&type=sales&page_size=1000&offset=' + str(offset)
    requests_my_var = requests.get(url=url_sales_count,headers=header)
    print(requests_my_var.status_code)
    offset = offset + 1000
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you. :) What a bonehead error by me.